# Generate dataframe with timeseries index starting today and fixed interval

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, time-series

I'm trying to generate pandas dataframe with timeseries index with the fixed interval. As an input parameters I need to provide set start and end date. The challenge is that the generated index starts either from month start  freq='3MS' or month end with freq='3M'. That cannot be defined in number of days as the whole year needs to have exact 4 periods and the start date needs to be as the defined start date.
The expected output should be in this case:
2020-10-05
2021-01-05
2021-04-05
2021-10-05

Any ideas appreciated.

```
interpolated = pd.DataFrame( index=pd.date_range('2020-10-05', '2045-10-05', freq='3M'),columns['dummy'])
```

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be in this case:
2020-10-05
2021-01-05
2021-04-05
2021-10-05

Comment: Unfortunately not understand :(

Comment: The first date cannot be 2020-10-30 or 2020-11-01 but 2020-10-05